# How can I ping a non-english hostname in Windows?

Tags: windows, localization

Does windows support non-english hostnames? In such a case what is the netbios name of the host and how can I ping it from the command line?

Comment: Did you try it? Why not?

Comment: Netbios names are restricted to ASCII only. If a computer has a non-english hostname, what is its netbios name?

Comment: Are you talking about [internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)?

Answer (score -1):

From Wikipedia article on [Hostnames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names):

> > The Internet standards (Request for Comments) for protocols mandate that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen ('-'). The original specification of hostnames in RFC 952, mandated that labels could not start with a digit or with a hyphen, and must not end with a hyphen. However, a subsequent specification (RFC 1123) permitted hostname labels to start with digits. No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are permitted.

So, if by non-English you mean using characters that are not ASCII, then I must presume the answer is no, as such hostnames can not legally exist.

Comment: Answer is wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Answer (score -1):

Every Unicode hostname has a non-Unicode equivalent. After passing the value through `IdnMapping()` you always get an ASCII string back that can be used. If your command prompt can't accept the Unicode input, ping it with its ASCII equivalent.

I found this site (no affiliation) that will do the conversion online: https://www.punycoder.com/ however with modern (2021) browsers if you type the name into the address bar and press enter the ASCII version will appear, but only if it contains characters not in your localization's characters. This was added as scam-deterrence so it may be modified in the future.